# A community of 'Painters in Crete' or 'Painters on Crete'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm creating a community of painters who live and work on the island of Crete?  Should I call the community 'Painters in Crete' or 'Painters on Crete'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally use the word **on** with (smallish) islands.  But it is not an absolute rule, and there are exceptions; for instance, "in Bermuda" is used much more often than "on Bermuda", while "in St Croix" and "on St Croix" are on par.

Comment: What do you think of **on the world**? _Nothing they encountered on Origae-6, he reflected— no matter how ferocious, no matter how predatory—could intimidate them following their experience **on the world** they were fleeing._ _Like the Engineers who had raised a great city **on the world** shrinking behind the Covenant, snuffed out by an invention of their own hand._

Comment: **on the world they were fleeing** is idiomatic.  The object of preposition **on** is a surface or thing which can be gotten off of.

Comment: Would it be less idiomatic put as _experience **in** the world they were fleeing_?

Comment: If the "world" is only figuratively a world but is actually a milieu (crime underworld, demi-monde,  white-supremacist enclave, etc) then we can speak of experiences **in** it.  But if it is literally a world, a planetary world on which one has landed (by  spaceship) then we would speak of experiences **on** it.

Comment: And so one would speak of European experiences **in** the New World as the Americas are only figuratively a world, not literally another planet.

Comment: Thank you very helpful too and great to read the sections you've used!

Answer (score 1):

We say "on" an island, but "in" a country or political subdivision.

Create is both an island and an "administrative region" of Greece, so either would be valid. It probably doesn't matter in a context like this whether you are talking about the place as an island or the place as a region. If it does, you should probably add words to clarify, like "in the region of Crete" versus "on the island of Crete".